# Installed Java 11, opened Jshell, command typed is not shown and hitting enter does not do anything

Tags: java, command-prompt, jshell

I uninstalled Java 8, installed Java 11 configured environment path. Opened command prompt in administrator mode, typed jshell which opened jshell and shows following text:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.10
|  For an introduction type: /help intro
jshell>
```

Now when I type some command/text, it is not visible in command prompt and hitting enter button too doesn't affects anything. However if i press ctrl+c, it start showing previous typed command as shown in below image, but again hitting enter button doesn't do anything:

[my command prompt image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsd3z.png)

How to fix this issue. Please help.

Comment: Works for me. See this [image](https://imgur.com/a/35MxGfl). I am on Windows 10. My Java version is `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug with JShell](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215720) for a certain version of Java. Update your Java version and the problem should go away.

Comment: 11.0.10 is already the latest patch for Java 11 LTS, and the link you gave was for a ctrl+D bug, not the issue described by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple command:

```
jshell> System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

... and provide here if it prints:

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: anything i type is not shown in command prompt after i open JShell. Also hitting enter after typing any command doesn't works.

Comment: Update your java. It seems to be a bug as @mike said.